# Replacing underscores followed with lowercase letter

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I want to be able to replace all underscores followed by a lowercase letter to a dot with sed. Is it possible?

replacing

`foo_bar`

with

`foo.bar`

Cheers

Comment: I think `sed 's/_\([a-z]\)/.\1/g'` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew or `[[:lower:]]` to avoid locale issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
echo 'foo_bar_BAR_space' | sed 's/_\([[:lower:]]\)/.\1/g'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/IibYXp)

Details:

- `_` - underscore
- `\([[:lower:]]\)` - capturing group matching a lowercase  letter and placing it in Group 1
- `.\1` - the replacement: a dot + the lowercase letter captured into Group 1
- `/g` - matches multiple occurrences of the defined pattern.